# Is there any open source library is available in android for resizing the image?

Tags: android, android-image

I wish to know if any **open source libraries** are available for resizing the image in Android. Because in my application i used camera to capture the image. The image supported sizes are differed from device to device. So here i used the top most size of the device for example HTC Wildfire has 19 sizes i used 2592x 1952 (WxH). Here i want to re-size the actual image with the size of 250x250 without any loss or stretch in image. I Searched in Google and StackOverflow, i got this Solutions [Thumbnailator](http://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator/) and [imgscalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/), unfortunately i can't implement in my application ( I doesn't know it support android, if yes means kindly post the solution how can i implement). When i  add ThumNailator jar in /libs folder, and i add this code snippet in my code,

```
            Thumbnails.of(new File(sdRoot + dir + fileName).listFiles())
                    .size(100, 100).outputFormat("JPEG")
                    .outputQuality(0.85)
                    .toFiles(Rename.PREFIX_DOT_THUMBNAIL);
```

it shows the notification like`"The type java.awt.image.BufferedImage cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"` . How can i re-size the captured image with my custom size.

Comment: You don't have to import libraries in java/android to do basic image manipulation like resizing. And most of the time you just have to decode it and pass it to the view.

Comment: @dystroy: i added all java and Android libraries but it says the same notification which i mentioned

Comment: Android Bitmap and Bitmap.Factory class has functionality what you want, You don't need to use any other library..

Comment: @user370305: When i use Bitmap.Factory, when i resize the image it stretched or i get any portion of the image. Here i i want what i mentioned two Jars do.

Comment: @Aerrow Thumbnailator *will not* work on Android, as it requires Java 2D and Java Image I/O which is available as part of Java SE, but unavailable under Android. (I'm the developer of the Thumbnailator library.)

Comment: @coobird: Thanks for your valuable comment. If any think like Thumbnailator for android. Because i need the exact functionality. one more thing, you did a good job in Thumbnailator.

Comment: @Aerrow I haven't done enough Android development to be knowledgeable enough to find/recommend any alternatives. Also, thank you for your kind words :)

Comment: Well, if you need to resize and save the resized image, you could draw in on a canvas an then save it, you can find samples here in SO. But with a minor caveat that quality is horrible, if compared with Core Graphics from iOS for example. But I guess that with small sizes like that won't be an issue

Comment: Have you found any solution to this ?

Comment: @xe4me:  I used picasso library for http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: @Aerrow , I thought picasso is for downloading images , can you tell me how did you use it for resizing ? thanks

Comment: Picasso.with(context)
  .load(<ImageURI>)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)