# How resize the image bitmap with the custom layout height and width

Tags: android, bitmap

I am using the fallowing solution to resize the bitmap. But it results portion of the image is lost.

Here is is my code.

```
 BitmapFactory.Options bmFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmFactoryOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            bmFactoryOptions.inMutable = true;
            bmFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = 2;
            Bitmap originalCameraBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(pData, 0, pData.length, bmFactoryOptions);
            rotatedBitmap = getResizedBitmap(originalCameraBitmap, cameraPreviewLayout.getHeight(), cameraPreviewLayout.getWidth() - preSizePriviewHight(), (int) rotationDegrees);

 public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight, int angle) {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
        DeliverItApplication.getInstance().setImageCaptured(true);
        return resizedBitmap;
    }
```

And here is the image height and width : Preview surface size:352:288 Before resized bitmap width : 320 Height : 240 CameraPreviewLayout width : 1080 Height : 1362 Resized bitmap width : 1022 Height : 1307

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244799/resizing-pictures-while-still-preserving-quality-in-android

Check this. in this getscaledImage() method their will be 
      float maxHeight = 800.0f;
        float maxWidth = 600.0f;
change it as per your requirement.

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Your java code is right but you haven't care about Aspect Ratio of Image thats whys your Image Portion is cutting.

Original Image Height and Width :

```
Height  = 352;
Width   = 288; 

Aspect Ratio = h/w; => Ratio = 1.2;
```

and you taken new width and height :

```
newHeight = 320;
newWidth  = 240;
```

But if we take Image Height as 320 then according Image Aspect Ratio Its Width becomes :

```
calculated width  = newHeight /Ratio; => 320/1.2= 266.66= 267;
calculated width  = 267;

difference of portion cutting is = calculated width -newWidth;
                                 = 267 -240 ;
                                 = 27 ;
```

So you need to take height and width for new bitmap.

```
newHeight = 320;
newWidth  = 267 ;
```

Comment: Here my image actual width and height  are 320 and 340 , want to create the image with 1080 and 1362. After resized it to custom width and height the bitmap width and height are 1022 and 1307.

Comment: You can take aspect ratio for increase height and width.

Comment: I need to get image with max supported size, the image captured by my mobile always giving 88:72

Comment: have you try to get your image from Image Uri. Think you have got thumbnail.

Comment: No, i am not getting image through uri, will capture image directly and then captured image is displayed to the user  in layout. When onPictureTaken method get invoked, resizing the image with layout height and width.

Comment: the above are the classes please suggest me on this.

Answer (score 0):

public class MarkableImageCaptureActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MarkableImageCaptureActivity.class);

```
@InjectView(R.id.top_menu_bar)
private LinearLayout topMenuLayout;
@InjectView(R.id.top_menu_title)
private TextView topMenuTitleTV;
@InjectView(R.id.image_desc_edittext)
private EditText imageDescEditText;
@InjectView(R.id.camerapreview_layout)
private FrameLayout cameraPreviewLayout;
@InjectView(R.id.btn_camera_capture)
private Button captureBtn;
@InjectView(R.id.btn_camera_save)
private Button saveBtn;
@InjectView(R.id.btn_camera_cancel)
private Button cancelBtn;
@InjectView(R.id.edit_captured_image_layout)
private RelativeLayout editCapturedImageLayout;
@InjectView(R.id.edit_captured_image)
private ImageView editCapturedImage;
@InjectView(R.id.color_container_layout)
private LinearLayout colorContainerLayout;
@InjectView(R.id.btn_markable_red)
private Button btnMarkableRed;
@InjectView(R.id.btn_markable_blue)
private Button btnMarkableBlue;
@InjectView(R.id.btn_markable_green)
private Button btnMarkableGreen;
@InjectView(R.id.btn_markable_white)
private Button btnMarkableWhite;
@InjectView(R.id.btn_markable_black)
private Button btnMarkableBlack;
@InjectView(R.id.btn_undo)
private TextView capturedImageUndo;

private MarkableImageView editableCapturedImageview;

@InjectView(R.id.flashSwitch)
private ToggleButton flashToggle;


private static final int DIALOG_CAPTURE_EXCEPTION = 2101;
private static final int DIALOG_CAPTURING_EXCEPTION = 2102;
private static final int DIALOG_SAVE_EXCEPTION = 0;
private String imageFileName = null;
private File imageFile = null;
private Stop targetStop = null;
private int stopId = DIntent.VALUE_INVALID_ID;
private float rotationDegrees = 0;

private Camera camera = null;
private CameraPreview cameraPreview;
private Bitmap rotatedBitmap;
private static final int PRIMARY_CAMERA_ID = 0;
private boolean imageCaptured = false;
private boolean inPreview = false;
private boolean isFlashSupports;
private boolean isCapturing = false;
private boolean isFlashOn;
private boolean isDocNameEditable;
private String imageDesc = "";
private Handler focusHandler = null;
private int captureType;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_camera_for_photo_capture);
    setupTopMenuBar(topMenuLayout, null, getString(R.string.menuitem_back), getString(R.string.menuitem_done), true, true, new ImageCaptureTopMenuListener());
    focusHandler = new Handler();
    editableCapturedImageview = (MarkableImageView) findViewById(R.id.editable_captured_imageview);
    Bundle intentBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    isDocNameEditable = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(DIntent.EXTRA_OBJECT_TYPE_DOCUMENT_EDITABLE, false);
    imageDesc = getIntent().getStringExtra(DIntent.EXTRA_OBJECT_TYPE_DOCUMENT_NAME);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        stopId = savedInstanceState.getInt(DIntent.EXTRA_STOP_ID);
        imageDesc = savedInstanceState.getString(DIntent.EXTRA_IMAGE_DESC);
        imageCaptured = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(DIntent.EXTRA_IS_IMAGE_CAPTURED);
        inPreview = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(DIntent.EXTRA_IN_PREVIEW);
        isFlashOn=savedInstanceState.getBoolean(DIntent.FLASH_MODE_ON);
        if (imageCaptured) {
            rotatedBitmap = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(DIntent.EXTRA_IMAGE_BITMAP);
        }
    }
    captureType = intentBundle.getInt(DIntent.EXTRA_TYPE_CAPTURE);
    if (captureType == DIntent.EXTRA_TYPE_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
        stopId = intentBundle.getInt(DIntent.EXTRA_STOP_ID);
        try {
            targetStop = getDbHelper().getStopDao().queryForId(stopId);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("Exception finding stop by Id!!", e);
        }
    }
    isFlashSupports = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
    if (isFlashSupports) {
        flashToggle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        flashToggle.setOnClickListener(this);
    } else {
        flashToggle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    captureBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    saveBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageDescEditText.setText(imageDesc);
    if (AndroidUtility.isValidTrimmedString(imageDesc)) {
        if (!isDocNameEditable) {
            imageDescEditText.setEnabled(false);
        }
    } else {
        imageDescEditText.setEnabled(true);
    }
    editCapturedImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMarkableWhite.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMarkableRed.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMarkableBlue.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMarkableGreen.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMarkableBlack.setOnClickListener(this);
    capturedImageUndo.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    logger.info("onStart:imageCaptured" + imageCaptured);
    boolean isImageCaptured = DeliverItApplication.getInstance().isImageCaptured();
    if (!isImageCaptured) {
        if (rotatedBitmap != null) {
            activateCapturedImageView(rotatedBitmap);
        } else {
            activatePreviewLayout();
        }
    }
}

private void activateCapturedImageView(Bitmap rotatedBitmap) {
    cameraPreviewLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    editableCapturedImageview.setCapturedBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
    editableCapturedImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    editCapturedImageLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    captureBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    saveBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    saveBtn.requestFocus();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) editableCapturedImageview.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    layoutParams.width = rotatedBitmap.getWidth();
    layoutParams.height = rotatedBitmap.getHeight();
    editableCapturedImageview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    logger.info("Inside activateCapturedImageView");
    releaseCamera();
}

private void activatePreviewLayout() {
    logger.info("Insie activatePreviewLayout");
    cameraPreviewLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    editableCapturedImageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    editCapturedImageLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    captureBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    captureBtn.requestFocus();
    saveBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    logger.info("onResume");
    if (rotatedBitmap == null || inPreview) {
        activateCameraPreview();
    }
}

public void activateCameraPreview() {
    logger.info("activateCameraPreview");
    camera = getCameraInstance(camera);
    if (camera != null) {
        cameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, camera);
        rotationDegrees = getCameraDisplayOrientation(this, PRIMARY_CAMERA_ID);
        camera.setDisplayOrientation((int) rotationDegrees);
        cameraPreviewLayout.addView(cameraPreview);
        inPreview = true;
        isCapturing = false;
        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        if (isFlashSupported(params)) {
            logger.info("activateCameraPreview: Flash Mode:"+ isFlashOn);
            if (isFlashOn) {
                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
            } else {
                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            }
        } else {
            flashToggle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        camera.setParameters(params);
        enableAutoFocusMode(camera);
    }
}

private Runnable doFocusRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (camera != null) {
            focusHandler.removeCallbacks(doFocusRunnable);
            if (CameraPreview.isCameraPreviewStarted) {
                try {
                    camera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);
                    logger.info("doFocusRunnable autofocus set");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Error while calling autofocus in camera."+e);
                }
            } else {
                logger.info("doFocusRunnable isCameraPreviewStarted false. Postdelay for 2 seconds");
                focusHandler.postDelayed(doFocusRunnable, 2000);
            }
        }
    }
};

Camera.AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCallback = new Camera.AutoFocusCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0, Camera arg1) {
        if (camera != null) {
            logger.info("Excuting onAutoFocus callback");
            focusHandler.postDelayed(doFocusRunnable, 2000);
        }
    }
};

public Camera getCameraInstance(Camera oldCamera) {
    Camera newCamera = null;
    try {
        logger.info("attempt to get a Camera instance");
        if (oldCamera == null) {
            logger.info("oldCamera is null.Opening Camera");
            newCamera = Camera.open(PRIMARY_CAMERA_ID);
        } else {
            logger.info("oldCamera is not null.Releasing it and Opening Camera");
            oldCamera.release();
            newCamera = Camera.open(PRIMARY_CAMERA_ID);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)");
    }
    return newCamera; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    logger.info("onPause");
    releaseCamera();
}

private void releaseCamera() {
    if (null != camera) {
        try {
            focusHandler.removeCallbacks(doFocusRunnable);
            CameraPreview.isCameraPreviewStarted = false;
            camera.cancelAutoFocus();
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
            cameraPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cameraPreview = null;
            inPreview = false;
            logger.info("Camera released successfully ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error while releasing camera in releaseCamera()."+e);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    logger.info("onSaveInstanceState");
    outState.putInt(DIntent.EXTRA_STOP_ID, stopId);
    outState.putBoolean(DIntent.EXTRA_IS_IMAGE_CAPTURED, imageCaptured);
    outState.putBoolean(DIntent.EXTRA_IN_PREVIEW, inPreview);
    outState.putString(DIntent.EXTRA_IMAGE_DESC, imageDesc);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    logger.info("onDestroy");
    DeliverItApplication.getInstance().setImageCaptured(false);
}

public float getCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity, int cameraId) {
    CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
    Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
    int displayOrientation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int infoOrientation = info.orientation;
    float degrees = 0;
    switch (displayOrientation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
    }

    float result;
    if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        logger.info("Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT");
        result = (infoOrientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
    } else { // back-facing
        logger.info("Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK");
        result = (infoOrientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    logger.info("Display Rotation:" + displayOrientation + " & infoOrientation:" + infoOrientation + " & degrees:"
            + degrees + " & info.facing:" + info.facing + " & result:" + result);
    return result;
}

private void captureImage() {
    try {
        if (camera != null) {
            //camera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);
            isCapturing = true;
            logger.info("Taking picture while clicking Capture button");
            camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallBack);
        } else {
            if (rotatedBitmap == null) {
                showDialog(DIALOG_CAMERA_UNAVAILABLE);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        releaseCamera();
        logger.error("Error in camera initialization in StartCaptureForPhoto screen.");
        activatePreviewLayout();
        activateCameraPreview();
    }
}

private PictureCallback pictureCallBack = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] pData, Camera pCamera) {
        BitmapFactory.Options bmFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmFactoryOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        bmFactoryOptions.inMutable = true;
      //  bmFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = 2;
        Bitmap originalCameraBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(pData, 0, pData.length, bmFactoryOptions);
        logger.info("before resized bitmap width : "+originalCameraBitmap.getWidth() + " Hieght : "+ originalCameraBitmap.getHeight());
        rotatedBitmap = getResizedBitmap(originalCameraBitmap, cameraPreviewLayout.getHeight(), cameraPreviewLayout.getWidth() - preSizePriviewHight(), (int) rotationDegrees);
        logger.info("cameraPreviewLayout width : "+cameraPreviewLayout.getWidth() + " Hieght : "+ cameraPreviewLayout.getHeight());

        if (rotatedBitmap != null) {
            imageCaptured = true;
            activateCapturedImageView(rotatedBitmap);
        } else {
            imageCaptured = false;
        }
        isCapturing = false;
        originalCameraBitmap.recycle();
        flashToggle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
};

public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight, int angle) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
    DeliverItApplication.getInstance().setImageCaptured(true);
    return resizedBitmap;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View pView) {
    switch (pView.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_camera_capture:
            if (!isCapturing) {
                captureImage();
            } else {
                logger.error("Picture being captured.User clicked so fast.");
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btn_camera_save:
            if (imageCaptured) {
                String description = imageDescEditText.getText().toString();
                if (description != null && description.length() > 0) {
                    saveCapturedImage();
                } else {
                    imageDescEditText.setError((getString(R.string.error_photo_desc)));
                }
            }
            break;
        case R.id.edit_captured_image:
            colorContainerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            capturedImageUndo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editableCapturedImageview.setPaintBrushColor(Color.WHITE);
            break;

        case R.id.btn_markable_green:
            editableCapturedImageview.setPaintBrushColor(Color.parseColor("#6AD523"));
            break;

        case R.id.btn_markable_blue:
            editableCapturedImageview.setPaintBrushColor(Color.parseColor("#407FF0"));
            break;

        case R.id.btn_markable_red:
            editableCapturedImageview.setPaintBrushColor(Color.parseColor("#B0321B"));
            break;

        case R.id.btn_markable_white:
            editableCapturedImageview.setPaintBrushColor(Color.parseColor("#F7F5FA"));
            break;

        case R.id.btn_markable_black:
            editableCapturedImageview.setPaintBrushColor(Color.parseColor("#2A2A2C"));
            break;

        case R.id.btn_undo:
            editableCapturedImageview.onClickUndo();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_camera_cancel:
            releaseCamera();
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.flashSwitch:
            switchFlash();
        default:
            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle bundle) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_CAPTURE_EXCEPTION:
            DIAlertDialog captureErrorDialog = new DIAlertDialog(this, getText(R.string.dialog_camera_error)
                    .toString(), getText(R.string.dialog_capture_exception).toString(), null, null);
            return captureErrorDialog;

        case DIALOG_SAVE_EXCEPTION:
            DIAlertDialog imageSaveErrorDialog = new DIAlertDialog(this, getText(R.string.dialog_camera_error)
                    .toString(), getText(R.string.dialog_image_save_exception).toString(), null, null);
            return imageSaveErrorDialog;
        case DIALOG_CAPTURING_EXCEPTION:
            DIAlertDialog capturingDialog = new DIAlertDialog(this, getText(R.string.dialog_camera_error)
                    .toString(), getText(R.string.dialog_capturing_exception).toString(), null, null);
            return capturingDialog;
        default:
            return super.onCreateDialog(id, bundle);
    }
}

private class ImageCaptureTopMenuListener implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && v.getId() == R.id.top_left_menu_item) {
            onBackPressed();
        } else if (v.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && v.getId() == R.id.top_right_menu_item) {
            if (imageCaptured) {
                String description = imageDescEditText.getText().toString();
                if (description != null && description.length() > 0) {
                    saveCapturedImage();
                } else {
                    imageDescEditText.setError((getString(R.string.error_photo_desc)));
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

private void switchFlash() {
    if (camera == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        if (rotatedBitmap != null) {
            activateCapturedImageView(rotatedBitmap);
        } else {
            activatePreviewLayout();
        }
        isFlashOn = true;
    } else {
        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        if (rotatedBitmap != null) {
            activateCapturedImageView(rotatedBitmap);
        } else {
            activatePreviewLayout();
        }
        isFlashOn = false;

    }
}

private int preSizePriviewHight() {
    int defaultSize = 100;
    switch (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
            defaultSize = 75;
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
            defaultSize = 80;
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
            defaultSize = 120;
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
            defaultSize = 160;
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
            defaultSize = 430;
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
            defaultSize = 460;
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
    return defaultSize;
}

private void enableAutoFocusMode(Camera camera) {
    try {
        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        List<String> focusParameterList = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
        if (focusParameterList != null && focusParameterList.size() > 0) {
            logger.info("Supported focus mode:"+focusParameterList);
            if (focusParameterList.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
                logger.info("enableAutoFocusMode: Starting focus mode");
                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
                camera.setParameters(params);
                /*
                Below line commented due to crash issue in focus mode because of autoFocus call before start preview
                So we are giving 2 sec delay for autoFocus.
                 */
                //camera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);
                focusHandler.postDelayed(doFocusRunnable, 2000);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error while setting AutoFocus in Camera."+e);
    }


}

private boolean isFlashSupported(Camera.Parameters params) {
    if (params != null) {
        List<String> flashModes = params.getSupportedFlashModes();
        if(flashModes == null) {
            return false;
        }
        for(String flashMode : flashModes) {
            if(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON.equals(flashMode)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (editableCapturedImageview != null) {
        editableCapturedImageview.resetCanvas();
    }
}
```

}

public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

```
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CameraPreview.class);
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private Camera camera;
private List<Size> cameraSizeList;
private Camera.Parameters cameraParameters;
public static boolean isCameraPreviewStarted = false;

public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    logger.info("Inside CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera)");
    this.camera = camera;
    isCameraPreviewStarted = false;
    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    surfaceHolder = getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        if (camera != null) {
            logger.info("Camera Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.");
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.startPreview();
            isCameraPreviewStarted = true;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error occured in surfaceCreated.", e);
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    logger.info("Camera SurfaceView Destroyed.");
    isCameraPreviewStarted = false;
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("onsurfaceChanged : preview surface does not exist");
        }
        return;
    }
    try {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("onsurfaceChanged :stop preview before making resize/rotate/reformatting changes");
        }
        isCameraPreviewStarted = false;
        camera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("onsurfaceChanged :Ignored surfaceChanged because tried to stop a non-existent preview", e);
    }

    if (camera != null) {
        cameraParameters = camera.getParameters();
        cameraSizeList = cameraParameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        cameraParameters.setPreviewSize(getMaxSupportedVideoSize().width, getMaxSupportedVideoSize().height);
        surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(getMaxSupportedVideoSize().width, getMaxSupportedVideoSize().height);
        camera.setParameters(cameraParameters);

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("onsurfaceChanged : made resize/rotate/reformatting changes:preview size:"
                    + String.valueOf(getMaxSupportedVideoSize().width) + ":"
                    + String.valueOf(getMaxSupportedVideoSize().height));
        }
    }

    try {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("onsurfaceChanged :start preview with new settings");
        }
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
            logger.info("onsurfaceChanged :start preview with new settings");
            isCameraPreviewStarted = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("onsurfaceChanged :Error while resetting camera preview on surfaceChanged.", e);
    }
}

public Size getMaxSupportedVideoSize() {
    int maximum = cameraSizeList.get(0).width;
    int position = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cameraSizeList.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (cameraSizeList.get(i).width > maximum) {
            maximum = cameraSizeList.get(i).width; // new maximum
            position = i - 1;
        }
    }
    if (position == 0) {
        int secondMax = cameraSizeList.get(1).width;
        position = 1;
        for (int j = 1; j < cameraSizeList.size() - 1; j++) {
            if (cameraSizeList.get(j).width > secondMax) {
                secondMax = cameraSizeList.get(j).width; // new maximum
                position = j;
            }

        }
    }
    return cameraSizeList.get(position);
}
```

}